# Lost files after running git reset --hard before initial commit

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-reset

So, I did something very stupid: i started a project, did quite a lot of work on it, and then I initialized a git repo. I ran `git add` to add all of the project files, but i wanted to exclude one file, so I quickly ran `git reset --hard` **before making an initial commit**.

Now all the files have disappeared from the repo and I have no clue how to restore them, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is there an alternative, bypassing git?

Comment: If you're asking whether you have something other than git  tracking those files (e.g. my IDE stores a local history), we can't tell you that.

Comment: Yes! Thank god for PyCharm, and thank you for making me dig deeper into its abilities to store local history (i did try that initially, but to no avail). I managed to restore all my files and I commited them instantaneously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've run `git add`, the blobs have been added to the repository and are stored there, even though they've been deleted from the working tree.  You can find all of these blobs by running `git fsck --dangling`, like so:

```
$ git fsck --dangling
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (dev)
notice: No default references
dangling blob 257cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99
missing tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```

Then, you can take each of the dangling blobs and inspect them:

```
$ git cat-file blob 257cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99
foo
```

Once you know where the file is supposed to be, you can redirect the output of that command to an appropriate file.  Do that with all the dangling blobs, and you can recover your working tree.

For future reference, `git reset --hard` completely blows away the contents of your working tree, removing all changes.  If you've added a file for the first time and decide later that you'd rather not have, you can simply run `git rm --cached FILE` to unstage it.  Note that by default, `git status` provides this hint for you to help you out.

Comment: For a brand-new repo like this `git fsck --lost-found` is probably fastest, then just rename the stuff in `.git/lost-found`

Comment: Thank you very muuch for your answer! Do you happen to know why for some blobs `$ git cat-file` produces a clear code for a file, but in some cases, it produces weird binary-looking string of random characters, with some actual parts of the original code (mostly function names) in between them?

Comment: Some of those files are binary files that you may have had in your repository.  If you don't want to save them, just ignore those blobs.